# Как считать текст из textBox?

Tags: c++-cli

Мне нужно считать текст из textBox. Причем нужно так считать, чтоб потом работать с этим текстом. И тут проблема - в char можно считать только 1 символ, пытался сохранить в string, но выскакивает ошибка, типа нельзя преобразовать `System.String` в `string` (я использую для преобразования `System::Convert::ToString`). Подскажите, куда лучше всего считать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String ^text = textbox->Text;
```

Из [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a19tt6sk.aspx):

```
public:
virtual property String^ Text {
    String^ get () override;
    void set (String^ value) override;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)) еще вопрос,как потом изменять определенние елементи переменной text ? Пробовал рассматривать как масив, но вискакивает ошибка.